# Truth table for the Boolean function $f(x,y) = x \oplus xy$ - Conflict with answer computed by sagemath

Tags: cryptanalysis, linear-cryptanalysis

By hand, I computed $f(x,y) = x \oplus xy = (0, 0, 1, 0)$ since, **in ascending (lexicographical) order**,

$f(0,0) = 0 \\ f(0,1) = 0 \\f(1,0) = 1 \\ f(1,1) =  0$

However, using the following code on sagemath

```
R.<x,y> = BooleanPolynomialRing(2)
B = BooleanFunction( x+x*y)
B.truth_table(format='int')
```

The answer is `(0, 1, 0, 0)`. I tried with other Boolean functions of two variables and I'm getting different answers from what I calculate by hand. Another example is $f(x,y) = x$. By hand, the answer is $f = (0,0,1,1)$ but using sage, it is $(0, 1, 0, 1)$.
Is it that the order in which the bits are calculated is incorrect?

*A few details for context*

I'm specifically interested in the convention regarding Boolean functions. For example, there are tasks that ask to find the ANF of a boolean function given in the $f = (b_1,b_2, \ldots , b_n)$ where $b_i$ is either $0$ or $1$. In the textbooks I have checked, it is often assumed that these values are in ascending order.
In [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/41040/85631), for instance, the truth table was calculated in ascending order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The truth table

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
x & y & xy & x \oplus xy \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 &  0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 &  1 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 &  0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 &  0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

and you can use [Boolean formulas](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/logic/sage/logic/boolformula.html)

```
f = propcalc.formula("x ^x&y")
f.truthtable()
```

outputs

```
x      y      value
False  False  False  
False  True   False  
True   False  True   
True   True   False
```

Comment: But what if I have, say, a function in a larger ring? What is the convention for ordering the bits? And if I'm given a boolean function in truth table form (i.e something like $f = (0101)$), doesn't that mean the entries are listed in ascending order?

Comment: @E.Nole The convention has to be specified, presumably in the software documentation. There really is no issue with the computation itself, right?

Comment: Although, I've given the answer, actually, there is ask.sageMath for your questions. This is rather a usage of sagemath. There is no convention, lex, inv_lex, grad, etc are possible examples.

Comment: @kodlu I think it is more relevant here because I'm specifically concerned about the convention of writing out truth tables for boolean functions. Kindly see the few remarks I have added to the question. Also, I think there would be some issues if the order of the truth values is not known beforehand. For example,   $f=(0100)$ would mean $f(1) = True$ in one case whereas it would mean $f(1) = False$ in the other case, and yet it's the same function.

Comment: It is a matter of taste on the truth table, some uses to start false, some - like me - used to start 1 since I've seen logic. So, from the docs, you should see the order like [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/pbori/pbori.html) and you can specify it according to yo your need.

Comment: Also, note that; in commutative algebra, the order affects the result.